# Passive ftp connection issue for aws/pure-ftpd

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos6, ftp

I have a centos server running pure-ftp via aws. I have configured PureDB and added a user with correct permissions. I have opened up inbound ports 20/21 and 49152-65534 within the aws security group and then mapped these ports back into pure-ftpd using the `Passive Port Range` setting in the pure-ftpd config file. At this stage testing on the machine using `ftp localhost` works as expected; I can connect with my user and list the files.

Now when trying to connect to the server from my machine I added the `ForcePassiveIP` setting on the server and set as the public ip for the aws instance, then tried to connect; `ftp <public-ip>`. The connection works, I can login, but 90% of the time the passive connection is hanging and just displays `227 Entering Passive Mode (<public-ip>,<ports>)` when I try to list the files. Similarly trying to upload a new file using an ftp client will hang and then fail:

`Response:  227 Entering Passive Mode (<public-ip>,<ports>)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`

Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening? Any help would be much appreciated.

NOTE: I had a similar issue on a Vagrant machine with the same OS/settings (minus the `ForcePassiveIP`setting) and this worked fine after running `modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp`, however this is not the case for the aws server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have well configured your pure-ftpd config file with these params :

```
PassivePortRange  49152 65534
ForcePassiveIP AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_IP
```

You can check what ports range is allowed on the OS with :

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Those settings were configured but what I did notice from your comment is that the `PassivePortRange` setting I had was incorrectly named as `Passive Port Range`. Changing this and restarting pure-ftpd fixed my issue. Cheers